# Promisify streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, eventemitter

I'm trying to promisify streams but it appears harder than I expected. Here is my attempt:

```
'use strict'

const Promise = require('bluebird')
const Twitter = require('twitter')

const TwitterStream = module.exports = function TwitterStream (config) {
  // init Twitter Streaming API for OAuth
  this.stream = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: config.get('/twitter/consumerKey'),
    consumer_secret: config.get('/twitter/consumerSecret'),
    access_token_key: config.get('/twitter/accessTokenKey'),
    access_token_secret: config.get('/twitter/accessTokenSecret')
  })
  .stream('statuses/filter', {
    track: config.get('/twitter/track')
  })
}

TwitterStream.prototype.receive = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.stream.on('data', resolve).on('error', reject)
  })
}

TwitterStream.prototype.destroy = function () {
  this.stream.destroy()
}
```

The main problem is that when I create the object

```
const stream = new TwitterStream(config)

stream.receive().then((data) => console.log(data))
```

when I execute only one object is read. no other data are streamed.

```
  TwitterStream.prototype.receive = function () {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this.stream
         .on('data', (data) => resolve(data)
         .on('error', (error) => reject(error))
       })
    }
```

Comment: I don't know the TwitterStream api. Is this stream opened indefinite, emitting the `data` event whenever new data (tweets) are available. And `end` is only called when the connection is interrupted?

Comment: @t.niese yes exactly

Comment: You cannot directly map Promises to this kind of streams. I'll try create an example how you would solve this.

Comment: You can't use promises for streams: They only yield one value. Use Rx.Observable instead

Comment: @olivarra1 ok thanks as i expected then it's not possible

Comment: How are you using the stream? What do you do with the data? Why do you want to use promises? How would you want to call `receive`?

Answer (score 2):

By using Rx extensions, it's pretty straightforward:

```
TwitterStream.prototype.receive = function () {
    return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.stream
            .on('data', (data) => observer.onNext(data))
            .on('error', (err) => observer.onError(err));
    });
}
```

And then

```
const stream = new TwitterStream(config)

stream.receive().subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Although it looks redundant (because you still have to pass in a callback when subscribing) it has the same benefits as when using a promise: You can apply operations such as map, compose, etc. which turns quite usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise in the callback of the `stream.on` function. Right now, the `receive` method when being called just returns a promise which once resolved returns the value or error.

Comment: Do you mean that? (edited the question) I've tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, because the function will return a Promise when it is called. If it isn't called more than once, the stream will not be read more than once. Registering an event handler would be a better way to approach this. My answer itself is wrong since I didn't understand the question properly. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not tested and most likely still buggy code to illustrate how you could do it with promises:

```
function defer() {
  var resolve, reject;
  var promise = new Promise(function() {
    resolve = arguments[0];
    reject = arguments[1];
  });
  return {
    resolve: resolve,
    reject: reject,
    promise: promise
  };
}


TwitterStream.prototype.receive = function() {

  this.stream
    .on('data', data => {
      this.dataCache = this.dataCache || [];
      this.dataCache.push(data);
      this.tryToSendData()
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      this.finished = true;
      this.tryToSendData()
    })
    .on('error', err => {
      this.lastError = err;
      // error handling still missing
    })

  return this;
}

TwitterStream.prototype.tryToSendData = function() {
  if (this.defered) {
    let defered = this.defered;
    this.defered = null;

    // if data is available or finished then pass the first element of buffer (or undefined)
    defered.resolve(this.dataCache.shift())
  }
}

TwitterStream.prototype.getNextData = function() {
  if (this.dataCache.length > 0 || this.finished) {
    // if data is available or finished then pass the first element of buffer (or undefined)
    return Promise.resolve(this.dataCache.shift());
  } else {
    // otherwise we need a defered object
    this.defered = defer();
  }
}
```

The usage could then look like this:

```
stream.receive().getNextData()
  .then(function processData(data) {
    if (data) {
      console.dir(data);

      // if data is available then continue requestin the data
      return stream.getNextData().then(processData);
    }
  })
```

It is a rare case where you could use Deferreds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at my, already promisified streams in [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet).

For your Twitter example this code should work well:

```
const stream = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: config.get('/twitter/consumerKey'),
    consumer_secret: config.get('/twitter/consumerSecret'),
    access_token_key: config.get('/twitter/accessTokenKey'),
    access_token_secret: config.get('/twitter/accessTokenSecret')
})
.stream('statuses/filter', {
   track: config.get('/twitter/track')
})
.pipe(new scramjet.DataStream)
```

Then perform any transformations you like... for example map the stream somehow and accumulate the stream into an array when you're done.

```
stream.map(
    function (a) { return modifyTheTweetSomehow(a); } // a Promise can be returned here
).accumulate(
    function(a, i) { a.push(i); },
    []
) // this returns a Promise that will be resolved on stream end.
```

I hope you like it. :)